# How to copy object that has a list with BeanUtils?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jpa

I'm working on a multi maven modules and I want to copy from entity to model with BeanUtils, here what I tried:

```
public List<ReleveBancaireCreationRequestDomain> getReleveBancaires() {
    List<ReleveBancaireCreationRequestDomain> releveBancaireList = new ArrayList<>();
    List<ReleveBancaireEntity> releveBancaireEntityList = releveBancaireRepository.findAll();
    for (ReleveBancaireEntity r : releveBancaireEntityList) {
        ReleveBancaireCreationRequestDomain releveBancaire = new ReleveBancaireCreationRequestDomain();
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(r, releveBancaire);
        releveBancaireList.add(releveBancaire);
    }
    return releveBancaireList;
}
```

This is my entity (with getters/setter/noargs/allargs):

```
@Entity
public class ReleveBancaireEntity{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long releveBancaireId;
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateReception;
    private String label;
    private int nbrLignes;
    private int nbrOperationCredit;
    private int nbrOperationDebit;
    private BigDecimal soldeInitial;
    private BigDecimal soleFinal;
    @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL,mappedBy = "releveBancaire", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonIgnoreProperties("releveBancaire")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<LigneReleveEntity> lignereleve = new ArrayList<>();
```

and this is my model (DTO Model):

```
public class ReleveBancaireCreationRequestDomain {

    private String label;
    private int nbrLignes;
    private int nbrOperationCredit;
    private BigDecimal soldeInitial;
    private BigDecimal soleFinal;
    private List<LigneReleveCreationRequestDomain> lignereleve = new ArrayList<>();
```

This is the output I'm getting:

```
[
    {
        "label": "RELEVE_1",
        "nbrLignes": 15,
        "nbrOperationCredit": 7,
        "soldeInitial": 145.20,
        "soleFinal": 158.36,
        "lignereleve": []
    }
]
```

The problem is that the fields get copied but the list does not it shows me an empty List. Is there any solution please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason the list isn't being copied is that they are of different types.  In your source object that list is of type `LigneReleveEntity`, in your target that list is of type LigneReleveCreationRequestDomain.

If you want to use the copy, then these either need to be of the same type, or implement the same interface.

Without knowing what those classes contain, here's a simple example assuming that they contain a single String value in a field called `value`.

Create an interface

```
public interface StringValue {
  String getValue();
}
```

On each of your classes, implement the interface

```
public class LigneReleveCreationRequestDomain implements StringValue {
```

...

```
public class LigneReleveEntity implements StringValue {
```

In your wrapper classes, reference these attributes by the interface and not the implementation:

```
private List<StringValue> lignereleve = new ArrayList<>();
```

...

```
private List<StringValue> lignereleve = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Hey maxwell thanks for response, I have a question so in interface `StringValue` should contains `LigneReleveEntity` values ? because `LigneReleveCreationRequestDomain` and `LigneReleveEntity` have the same fields.

Comment: That was just an example.  The interface you create should contain getters for all of the fields that you want to copy between the two objects.  If the two classes are identical and you do not want to use the same class in both locations, then yes, create an interface that has getter methods for all of properties.  Just based on your chosen names, I would create an interface named something like `LigneReleve`

Comment: Thanks maxwell for your help really appreciate that, just want to ask for a favor could you please give me an example of a copy method manually so in future I can use it on all operation of copy because I searched all over but didnt find a solution, I want to controll my copy pproperties. Really thanks a lot Maxwell.

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't have two identical classes and copy the properties between them.  If you're looking to create a DTO, I would create it with only the properties that you want to transfer.  In your main domain class, I would create a `to` method that converts it to the DTO.  For instance, if you have a `Person` class, add a method to it that looks like, `public PersonDTO toPersonDTO()` that constructs and returns the DTO straight from your Person class.